# Mapbox GL: How to show bounding box on top of a map

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, bounding-box

I am trying to show a physical bounding box on top of a map I have in a React/JS application. I want it to look similar to the picture below:

[image]

I already have a map, but I am having trouble getting a red box to appear. I currently have tried to do something like this, but there is no box in sight.

```
// Bounding Box
var southWest = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-73.9876, 40.7661);
var northEast = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-73.9397, 40.8002);
var boundingBox = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

I am not sure how to call bounding box to get it to show up on the map. How do I do this? I am very new to Mapbox, so I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question. Thanks in advance!

Note: I am *not* trying to get the map to zoom into the bounding box. I simply want the bounding box to appear on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need it but i was looking to do the same and found i can do it by using this https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

If you just modify the coördinaties to where your box needs to be it will do the trick. You will need 5 points to complete the shape.

```
map.addSource('route', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {},
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'LineString',
                    'coordinates': [
                        [2.34, 51.55],
                        [6.54, 51.55],
                        [6.54, 49.45],
                        [2.34, 49.45],
                        [2.34, 51.55],

                    ]
                }
            }
        })
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'route',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'route',
            'layout': {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#888',
                'line-width': 8
            }
        });
```